# Failed to get exe icon with SHGetFileInfo

Tags: c++, winapi, icons

I'm using cmake + nmake to build exe, I want to get the icon handle from the executable itself.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(test test.cpp test.rc)
```

test.rc:

```
IDI_ICON   ICON  DISCARDABLE  "test.ico"
IDI_ICON0   ICON  DISCARDABLE  "test.ico"
IDI_ICON1   ICON  DISCARDABLE  "test.ico"
IDI_ICON2   ICON  DISCARDABLE  "test.ico"
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    SHFILEINFO  sfi;
    memset(&sfi, 0, sizeof(sfi));
    DWORD_PTR ret = ::SHGetFileInfo("g:/workspace/test2/debug/test.exe",
                    0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_LARGEICON|SHGFI_SMALLICON|SHGFI_ICON);
    cout << hex;
    cout << ret << endl; // prints 0
    cout << sfi.hIcon << endl; // prints 0
}
```

The executable **g:/workspace/test2/debug/test.exe** does have icon, but the SHGetFileInfo failed to get the icon, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you tried to combine the `uFlags` parameter with a specific icon type `SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON` or `SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON`? You should also check the return value from `SHGetFileInfo()` to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Origin post updated with these parameters and return value.

Comment: and what is the return value?

Comment: The return value is 0. But how to get error information, the document doesn't metion anything about GetLastError.

Comment: Windows generally uses back-slashes as path separators, not forward-slashes - I'm not sure the `SHGetFileInfo` function accepts both. Also `SHGFI_LARGEICON|SHGFI_SMALLICON` is a bit of a contradiction. You can only get one at once.

Comment: have you called CoInitialize() prior to calling SHGetFileInfo()?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does the icon appear when viewing the exe file in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Cyclone: [SHGetFileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179.aspx) is not documented to set the last error code. Don't recommend to call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) unless the documentation explicitly asks you to.

Comment: @IInspectable - If you can read you notice that its an '?' since I was not sure?

Comment: @Cyclone: So, does that mean, that you aren't sure about your last comment either? At any rate, stackoverflow isn't the place to play guessing games.

Answer (score 2):

My best bet would be that you (as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) need to call `CoInitialize()` prior to trying to get extract the icon information. And if we have a windows function that can not handle forward slashes I would not be surprised:

> You must initialize Component Object Model (COM) with CoInitialize or OleInitialize prior to calling SHGetFileInfo.

So, the code code be changed to something like:

```
int main() {
  SHFILEINFO  sfi;

  // initialize COM library
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  memset(&sfi, 0, sizeof(sfi));
  DWORD_PTR ret = ::SHGetFileInfo("g:/workspace/test2/debug/test.exe",
                0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_LARGEICON | SHGFI_ICON);
  cout << hex;
  cout << ret << endl;
  cout << sfi.hIcon << endl;

  CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: The path separator on Windows is a backslash ("\"). While the *"file I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name"* ([Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx)), this conversion won't be done when paths have a "\\?\" prefix. Incidentally, this prefix pushes the path name limit to 32k Unicode characters for the file I/O functions. Since `SHGetFileInfo` is not part of the file I/O functions, the conversion is not contractual.

Answer (score 1):

As comment post by Jonathan Potter, it's caused by the back-slash. The code works after changing '/' to '\' in the file path.